# How do I display database records within the time range "Time.now" minus x hours?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, range, conditional-statements

I use a query with a Hash condition and a time range from "Time.now" to -24 hours.

```
@time_range = @time_now..(@time_now - 24*3600)
Model.all(:conditions => { :created_at => (@time_range) })
```

At the moment all database records, which have been created more than 24 hours ago, will not be displayed. All the records which are less than 24 hours "old", are displayed.

My goal is to replace the contant value 24 with a variable coming from the database column "duration". This column contains an integer value from 24 to 1 - depending on how the database record was created in the form.

So I need to access this "duration" column. But I don't know how do that in the Controller, since I have no model instance available. So I can't say for instance:

```
Model.duration*3600
```

or:

```
:duration*3600
```

Any hint is very much appreciated.

PS: This question is similar to [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284696/how-can-i-search-date-range-in-rails-with-variable-date). Unfortunately, I couldn't find the answer there.

Answer (score 0):

That one is a bit simpler to answer then you think. Rails has a sort of built in method system for calculating time.

If you want to go back a day you will only have to do 1.day.from_now or you can even do 2.day.from_now

This will return the data as a timestamp.

```
1.day.from_now.beginning_of_day

1.month.from_now.beginning_of_month

1.month.from_now

1.day.from_now
```

Comment: Thx. But I'm not sure, it answers my question properly. I want to replace 24 (hours) with variable which has a value 1 to 24. This variable comes from the database column "duration". I hope, it's now clearer what I mean.

Or do you want so say that

 "duration.from_now"

actually works?

Answer (score 0):

This code might be more what you are looking for. not exactly what you are talking about but I think it is built around the same idea that you were commenting about. Hope it can help.

```
def self.days_from_now(d)
    self.where("due_date >= ? AND due_date <= ? ", d.day.from_now.beginning_of_day, d.day.from_now.end_of_day)
end
```

Comment: Oh by the way this code is in my model if there was any confusion.

Comment: Thanks again. As you said it's not exactly what I'm talking, but a good beginning. The query gives you results between midnight (00:00) and 23:59. I'll try that approach and give you further feedback, asap.