# Querying a date range in Rails 3.2 is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Report page that generates reports of events. There is a datepicker and the user can put in a date range (Ex. March 1st - March 20th) and return all events where the event's :start_at begins within that range. I recently upgraded from Rails 3.0.11 to Rails 3.2.13 (I was careful to follow the RailsCasts episodes directly and jump from 3.0 to 3.1 and then from 3.1 to 3.2) and noticed that my reports no longer work but I have not made any changes to the Events controller or the Event model. My code looks as follows:

**events_controller.rb**

```
def reports
  if !params[:report_start].blank? && !params[:report_end].blank?
    @events = current_user.events.report(params[:report_start], params[:report_end])
  else
    @events = current_user.events.where(params[:search]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      @events = @events.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page]) 
    end
    format.xml  { render :xml => @events }
    format.pdf do
      pdf = ReportPdf.new(@events)
      send_data pdf.render, filename: "Event_Report.pdf",
                          type: "application/pdf"
    end
  end
end
```

**event.rb**

```
def self.report(report_start, report_end)
  where(:start_at => report_start.to_date..report_end.to_date)
end
```

Has the syntax of a query like this changed somewhere in the upgrade process?

I verified that Rails is still saving the date in the same format and it is working correctly everywhere else. The date output in Rails Console looks as follows:

```
start_at: "2013-04-25 00:00:00"
```

Any help would be appreciated as this is driving me crazy and looks correct to me. Thanks!

**Edit:** I found **[this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9962985/1609347)** on the topic and it looks like that response says to do it the way I am but nothing is happening.

The URL does change after cliking to generate the report and the URL generated looks as follows:

```
http://localhost:3000/reports?utf8=%E2%9C%93&direction=&sort=&event%5Breport_start%5D=&event%5Breport_end%5D=&commit=Generate+Report
```

Comment: I have to say that I'm using the same query in Rails 3.2.12 without any problem. Are you sure that the problem is in the date range? What are not exactly working now?

Comment: The URL changes and it acts like it's processing the query but nothing on the page is changing. If I have 5 dates that are very spread out and I have one event on March 2nd, I can pass it the date range March 1-4 which should only return the one event but instead all events are displaying.

Comment: I think that the parameters are wrong, could you put here the view where you are clicking to execute the report?

Comment: My view is here http://pastie.org/7084531

Answer (score 1):

I know I am answering my own question but I wanted to post the solution in case anyone else runs into this issue since I was able to get this working. The problem seems to be due to Rails handling time differently. The new code is as follows:

http://pastie.org/7107095

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def self.report(report_start, report_end)
  where('start_dt >= ? and end_dt <= ?',report_start,report_end)   
end
```

Comment: I know I am answering my own question but I wanted to post the solution in case anyone else runs into this issue since I was able to get this working. The problem seems to be due to Rails handling time differently. The new code is as follows (links are to code snippets):  
  
[events_controller.rb](http://pastie.org/7106998),  
  
[event.rb (model)](http://pastie.org/7107013),  
  
[report view](http://pastie.org/7107022)