# How compare time range using created_at fields on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to get the records only included on time range using default created_at Rails field. No matters the day was created.

I have this:

```
@start_time = test.start_time.strftime("%I:%M%p")
@end_time test.end_time.strftime("%I:%M%p")
@websites = device.websites.where(:created_at => @start_time..@end_time)
```

I was searching for something like this:

```
@websites = device.websites.where(:created_at::time => @start_time..@end_time)
```

This generate this SQL sentence without results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `websites`.* FROM `websites` WHERE `websites`.`device_id` = 2 AND (`websites`.`created_at` BETWEEN '16:10:00' AND '21:10:00')
```

But if I add time function to created_at field, works fine.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `websites`.* FROM `websites` WHERE `websites`.`device_id` = 2 AND (time(`websites`.`created_at`) BETWEEN '16:10:00' AND '21:10:00')
```

How is the best Rails way to do this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I search date range in Rails with variable date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284696/how-can-i-search-date-range-in-rails-with-variable-date)

Answer (score 1):

Rails automatically converts the time objects to the format that your database requires, so there is no need for strftime. You should be able to do it like this:

```
@websites = device.websites.where(:created_at => test.start_time..test.end_time)
```

Comment: I try it but not works, if I use mysql time function to convert created_at field works ok.